# why is my form being submitted twice when pressing enter or when using a barcode scanner?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have tried everything and it seems that the form is submitted twice only when pressing enter or using a barcode scanner which I want to use. I does not happen when clicking the "submit button". At first I thought I was executing the query twice but it's not the case. This is my code:

HTML file

```
<form id="formulario_ingreso" class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return ingresar();" method="POST">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="codigo" type="number" name="codigo" class="form-control" placeholder="Código" autofocus>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="select2 form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre">
                <option value="">Nombre (Solo si no existe código)</option>
                <?php
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($perfiles_query)){
                        echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["nombres"].' '.$row["apellidos"].'</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ingresar()">Ingresar</button>
</form>
```

SCRIPT file

```
<script>
   $("#formulario_ingreso").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
   });
</script>
<script>
   function ingresar(){
       var codigo = $("#codigo").val();
       var nombre = $("#nombre").val();
       if(codigo){

           $.post("evento/ingresar_asistencia.php", { codigo: codigo },
           function(data) {
                 $('#results').html(data);
                 $('#formulario_ingreso')[0].reset();
           });



       }else if(nombre){
           $.post("evento/ingresar_asistencia.php", { nombre: nombre },
           function(data) {
                 $('#results').html(data);
                 $('#formulario_ingreso')[0].reset();
           });
       }
    };

</script>
```

PHP FILE

```
<?php
require_once '../../../config.php';

if(isset($_POST["codigo"])){
    $codigo = $_POST["codigo"];
    echo $codigo;

    $asistencia_query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO asistencia (id_perfil, id_evento) VALUES (2,1) ");

}
```

Comment: it should submitted once, also remove `onsubmit="return ingresar();"`

Comment: bcoz you have calling twice ingresar() this functions, one is button click and form submit, remove at least one.

Comment: Scanners will virtually press enter?

Comment: Barcode scanners does include a 'press enter' command at the end of the scan. You can test any barcode scanner connect to your pc and scan to notepad or something and you'll see the text cursor will appear below on each scanned barcode.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code but in my case,  it's a one-time call **`ingresar()`** function when I click on the button.

Please remove **`onsubmit="return ingresar();"`** from you form tag. I think this one is creating the issue

Comment: I removed `onsubmit="return ingresar();"`  and changed the button from `type="button"` to `type="submit"` and that did the trick